# Clean Webpack Compiling Output

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm trying to clean my webpack compiling output to show only the files that are highlighted in the image below:

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're locked to a specific WP version, but it looks like you can use `excludeAssets: /^assets\/.*|favicon.ico|index.html/` as stated in https://webpack.js.org/configuration/stats/.